# Having trouble with the "updated" signal in libgweather

Tags: c, gtk, weather

Supposedly, after updating weather information, libgweather emits an "updated" signal:
https://developer.gnome.org/libgweather/stable/GWeatherInfo.html#GWeatherInfo-updated

I'm having trouble getting this to work.  Granted, I am pretty new to GTK programming, so I may be missing something obvious.  Here is my code:

```
#include <libgweather/gweather.h>

static void update_finish(GWeatherInfo *info, gpointer data)
{
    printf("update finished\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GWeatherInfo *info;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    info = gweather_info_new(NULL,GWEATHER_FORECAST_ZONE);
    g_signal_connect(info, "updated", G_CALLBACK(update_finish), NULL);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

The `update_finish()` function never appears to be called.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to add an explicit call to `gweather_info_update()`? In any case file a bug, either the documentation is out of sync with the code or it is a bug.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `gweather_info_update()` with no luck.  Just submitted a bug report -- thanks for the suggestion!